# Makefile with CUDA and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cuda, makefile

I'm trying to run the source code at the following URL:
https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/source/checkout

I'm running it on a server where MATLAB and CUDA 6 are installed, but when I do

```
make all
```

it returns the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `fft2_cuda.mexa64', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

This is how the Makefile looks:

```
# Define installation location for CUDA and compilation flags compatible
# with the CUDA include files.
CUDAHOME    = /usr/local/cuda
INCLUDEDIR  = -I$(CUDAHOME)/include
INCLUDELIB  = -L$(CUDAHOME)/lib -lcufft -Wl,-rpath,$(CUDAHOME)/lib
CFLAGS      = -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -fexceptions
COPTIMFLAGS = -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2

# Define installation location for MATLAB.
export MATLAB = /usr/local/matlab
#export MATLAB = /Applications/MATLAB_R2007b
MEX           = $(MATLAB)/bin/mex
MEXEXT        = .$(shell $(MATLAB)/bin/mexext)

# nvmex is a modified mex script that knows how to handle CUDA .cu files.
NVMEX = ./nvmex

# List the mex files to be built.  The .mex extension will be replaced with the
# appropriate extension for this installation of MATLAB, e.g. .mexglx or
# .mexa64.
MEXFILES = fft2_cuda.mex       \
           fft2_cuda_sp_dp.mex \
           ifft2_cuda.mex      \
           Szeta.mex

all: $(MEXFILES:.mex=$(MEXEXT))

clean:
    rm -f $(MEXFILES:.mex=$(MEXEXT))

.SUFFIXES: .cu .cu_o .mexglx .mexa64 .mexmaci

.c.mexglx:
    $(MEX) CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' COPTIMFLAGS='$(COPTIMFLAGS)' $< \
        $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.cu.mexglx:
    $(NVMEX) -f nvopts.sh $< $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.c.mexa64:
    $(MEX) CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' COPTIMFLAGS='$(COPTIMFLAGS)' $< \
        $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.cu.mexa64:
    $(NVMEX) -f nvopts.sh $< $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.c.mexmaci:
    $(MEX) CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' COPTIMFLAGS='$(COPTIMFLAGS)' $< \
        $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.cu.mexmaci:
    $(NVMEX) -f nvopts.sh $< $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)
```

By the way, doing

```
which matlab
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab
```

So, I tried changing the MATLAB directory to that in the Makefile, but it didn't work either.

Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Did you call the `make` from within MATLAB? This is what the [readme states](https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/source/browse/trunk/Matlab_Cuda_1.1/README.txt#49).

Comment: @m.s. Does it mean I have to call make after I execute matlab? I tried calling make in matlab, but it says undefined function..

Comment: execute **unix('make');** from within MATLAB

Comment: @m.s. I tried it, but it returns the same error :(

Comment: When looking [at the repository](https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FMatlab_Cuda_1.1), it seems like the files `fft2_cuda.c` etc. are missing.

Comment: The FFT-CUDA MATLAB code (including fft2_cuda.c) seems to be mirrored here:  https://github.com/mjt5v/Senior_Thesis/tree/master/Matlab_Cuda_1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Matlab_Cuda_1.1` dir in that repo does not contain the Mathlab CUDA plugin sources.

A copy of them could be found here: https://code.google.com/p/projektarbeitcuda/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Freference%2Fsrc%2FMatlab_CUDA_1.1

Get the files and put them into your `Matlab_Cuda_1.1` dir.

Also, before building don't forget to check and adjust the paths in the beginning of the Makefile (CUDAHOME, MATLAB, MEX, MEXEXT) so that they point to proper locations in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Is `fft_cuda` built from a `.c` file? I think there's a missing piece in the `.SUFFIXES` specification. I think it should work to simplify the Makefile a little like so:

```
# Everything up until the .SUFFIXES line is OK, but then:
.SUFFIXES: .c .cu $(MEXEXT)

.c$(MEXEXT):
    $(MEX) CFLAGS='$(CFLAGS)' COPTIMFLAGS='$(COPTIMFLAGS)' $< \
        $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)

.cu$(MEXEXT):
    $(NVMEX) -f nvopts.sh $< $(INCLUDEDIR) $(INCLUDELIB)
```

Comment: I did make clean and tried as suggested, but the same error :( maybe there should be some modification before SUFFIXES as well?

Comment: Hm, I looked at the source repository - I couldn't see any `fft_cuda` source files - so that's why the Makefile can't build one.

Comment: Is there any way to go around it? :(

Comment: Well I don't really know - https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/source/browse/trunk/README doesn't mention building in that directory.